# DataTable para de funcionar após atualização da página via AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-datatables

Tenho uma página com uma tabela que é atualizada via AJAX.
Dessa forma, tenho um combo que quando seleciono a opção, a tabela é atualizada sem dar refresh.

Nessa tabela, eu preciso da opção de ordenar e pensei em usar o DataTable.

A tabela segue o exemplo da imagem abaixo.

[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]

Quando entro na página, o order do DataTable funciona normalmente.
Entretanto, quando altero a opção no campo, por exemplo, para "Rodada 2", os dados da tabela são atualizados e o DataTable meio que some. 
O ordenar para de funcionar e só volta se eu der F5 na página.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tabelaNotaFinal').DataTable({
            "paging": false,
            "searching": false,
            "info": false,
            "language": {
                "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page",
                "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
                "info": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
                "infoEmpty": "No records available",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
            }
        });
    });
```

jquery-3.5.1.min.js
jquery.dataTables.min.js

Alguém já teve algum problema parecido?

Agradeço desde já.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjJHG.png

Answer (score 0):

O dataTable já tem a própria função de AJAX, que recebe os valores e atualiza automaticamente as linhas da tabela.

Eles tem várias opções de personalização, inclusive opção de fazer paginações nos registros.

Dê uma olhada na página da documentação que explica como aplicar o próprio AJAX do dataTable:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax